# React recommended bootstrap libraries

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have been using Angular but now I planning to use React for my next project. So I am getting familiar with React and I was wondering what addiontal libraries are recommended for funtionality like routing, rest calls, state management preferably using Typescript and with that in mind is there a best practice architecture when designing large scale app?

Comment: Not sure questions like this are allow on here.
But my personal go to is react-router, axios, and redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Angular for routing, REST calls & state management, and React for views.

Otherwise, the most popular are probably [GitHub's fetch() polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for REST, and [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for state management. Or just use the new [built-in `useReducer()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead.